# CSV file to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I want to convert a csv file with data like this in a multidimensional array.

```
1;name1;date1
2;name2;date2
```

The name of the file is vervangingen.csv. And I want the array to be like this:

```
Array (   

 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => name1
            [2] => date1
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => name2
        [2] => date1

    )

)
```

Currently I have this:

```
    $csv = array();
    $file = fopen('vervangingen.csv', 'r');

    while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
    {
        $csv[] = $result;
    }

    fclose($file);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($csv);
    echo '</pre>';
```

But this makes the array look like this. I know there exists something like explode, but I don't know how exactly I would use it here. Could anyone help me maybe?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1;name1;date1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2;name2;date2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should set correct delimiter:

```
fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')
```

as described in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)